# Create JS Object Literal with Uninitialized Members

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, is there a way to create object literals with uninitialized instance variables?

The purpose would be to allow for iterating through the members using a for-in loop to initialize them in parallel with other similar objects for the sake of generalized code. At the moment, I am simply having to stick temporary dummy values (including "undefined") in for the members, so I was wondering if there is a way to get around having to do that.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this `var obj = {}` ?

Comment: No, all properties of an object must have a value, even if it's `undefined`. One alternate approach would be to keep an Array of property names, and iterate the Array when it comes time to initialize.

Comment: @SheikhHeera No, I was looking to still be able to do a `for x in obj`, so in theory something like `var obj = {x, y, z}`

Comment: @CrazyTrain Yeah, as of now that's looking like one of my cleaner options.

Comment: What's wrong with `undefined`? That's exactly what the value is meant for - existing but not initialised.

Comment: @BrendanCain, what about `obj = {x:null, y:null, z:null}` ?

Comment: Note that you can create a shortcut for `undefined`, for example `var _ = undefined; obj = { x:_, y:_, z:_ };` (though this specific shortcut is not great if you use underscore.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty nifty. It depends on [Object.definedProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Let's create an object

```
var obj = Object.create({});
```

Define some `enumerable` properties. These ones will show up when we iterate over the object

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'hardwork', {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable:   true,
  get: function() {
    // caution: hard work below!
    console.log("hard work began");
    return Math.random();
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'reallyhardwork', {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable:   true,
  get: function() {
    // caution: really hard work below!
    console.log("really hard work began");
    return [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
  }
});
```

This is a non-enumerable property; it won't be included in the for..in loop

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'hidden', {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable:   false,
  get: function() {
    console.log("hidden work happening now!");
    return "you should not see this";
  }
});
```

Finally, let's actually do some work

```
console.log("begin working");
for (var prop in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    console.log(obj[prop]);
  }
}
console.log("work ended");
```

Output

```
"begin working"
"hard work began"
0.038129367399960756
"really hard work began"
[ 0.9397948638070375, 0.6731829405762255, 0.2854277777951211 ]
"work ended"
```

**Note:** the hidden property was not displayed in the output, but it's still available if you need it.

```
obj.hidden
// => hidden work happening now!
// => you should not see this
```

---

Compare this to the following

```
var obj = {
  hardwork: Math.random(),
  reallyhardwork: [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()],
  hidden: "you should not see this"
};
```

Those `Math.random()` calls are run at the time the object is defined which means all the hard work is done up front; not lazy-loaded during iteration like the above example. Also note that if you want any properties to not be included in the loop, this way wouldn't work. You'll see below that the hidden property is displayed.

```
// no work is done except for iterating through values that have already been defined
for (var prop in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    console.log(obj[prop]);
  }
}
```

Output

```
0.7174121951684356
[ 0.7939756268169731, 0.4218691026326269, 0.8476794681046158 ]
"you should not see this"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy, just set it to *undefined*, for example with a *function*.

```
function createProperties(o, k) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < k.length; ++i)
        o[k[i]] = undefined; // or `void 0`
}
```

Then

```
var myObj = {}, key;
createProperties(myObj, ['foo', 'bar']);
for (key in myObj) console.log(key, myObj[key]);
// foo undefined
// bar undefined
```

There is no real benefit to doing this over using `null` or something that might be more useful.

---

Why do I suggest *undefined*? Consider the following.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var foo;
    console.log(foo, foo === undefined); // logs undefined true
    bar; // ReferenceError: bar is not defined
}());
```

So `var x;` has the same result as `var x = undefined;`. Next, consider

```
var arr1 = new Array(1),
    arr2 = [undefined];
arr1[0]; // undefined
arr2[0]; // undefined
arr1[0] === arr2[0]; // true
// look pretty similar, HOWEVER
arr1.hasOwnProperty(0); // false
arr2.hasOwnProperty(0); // true
```

So though you might get *undefined* turning up in places, it doesn't tell you if the property has been initialised

Comment: You could also easily add an extra parameter to my function to do defaults (if left blank would still be _undefined_). ....`o[k` looks like a little person, can't unsee!

Answer (score 0):

Your only resort is to actually define those keys on the instance or otherwise you cannot enumerate this property, but to avoid dummy data you can simply set the value to `undefined`.

```
var foo = function() {
    this.someInstanceMember = undefined;
};

var bar = new foo();
```

Things like `Object.keys(bar)` will show that `someInstanceMemeber` is defined, a for in loop will get it and `"someInstanceMember" in bar` is `true`.